# how can $\frac{kqq_o}{r}$ be $U$ for both a particle and a system of two particles?

Tags: energy

If there is a charge $q$, at a distance $r$ from it there is a voltage and the potential energy of a test charge $q_o$ would be $\frac{kqq_o}{r}$.

Now if I construct a system of two charges a distance $r$ apart, it has energy $\frac{kqq_o}{r}$.

I don't get this... How can the energy of any single particle (here $q$ or $q_o$) in the system be the energy of the combined system? Shouldn't the energy in the two particle system be $2\frac{kqq_o}{r}$?

Comment: One charged particle $q_1$ all by itself out in space has no potential energy at all. However, you can assign a potential to each point in space for that situation: $U = k q_1 / r$. If you now push a new particle with charge $q_2$ from infinite to a particular distance $r$ from $q_1$, then the energy it took you to do that push is $k q_1 q_2 / r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential energy is the energy associated with the interaction between two objects.  It's related to the force between two objects.  That is: potential energy requires two objects.

You can talk about the potential energy of one object, but you would be being a little loose with language.  We are in the habit of talking about the gravitational potential energy of an object near the surface of the earth.  But we really mean the potential energy of the earth-object system.   I guess it's just cumbersome and clumsy to keep saying "earth-object system", so we adopt an abbreviated way of expressing things.  This could lead to confusion ... as it has for you.

Answer (score 2):

The potential energy here is associated with the entire system, not with any one piece of it.

Often in problems we assume that one of the particles is fixed.  If so, it cannot realize any of the potential energy of the system.  Then it is possible to assign all of the potential energy to the other particle.

Comment: Seems that your last sentence conflicts with your first. MIght it be better to say "it is possible to assign all the change in potential energy to the addition of the other particle."?  As you say, the potential energy is associated with the entire system.